# Unable to activate HDMI output with AMD/Nvidia hybrid graphics card

Tags: drivers, radeon, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I have an Asus TUF Gaming FX505D Laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS.

And I'm unable to connect a Monitor with HDMI to my Laptop.

It has an AMD Radeon RX Vega 10 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 2060 Hybrid Graphic card.

```
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f11 (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c1)
```

I have the `nvidia-driver440` installed.

With `prime-select query` I only found `nvidia`.

If I try to start the `nvidia-settings` I get the following output:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:3752): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:39:36.941: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 12:39:36.945: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 12:39:36.945: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

And an empty window.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe's a bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kernel-package/+bug/1871721

Comment: Check out this link.
I have GTX1650 with AMD running ubuntu 18.04, Xrandr detected external HMDI device , but the monitor displayed blank black screen.
I solved it by following this link. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7?u=amith4504

Answer (score -1):

try to go to Applications-> Software & Update -> Additional Drivers and check if there aren't some blocked drivers related with nvidia or radeon. And just in case if you're trying to use your hdmi cable with the USB-C port, it just doesn't work on linux.

Comment: there are no other drivers and i dont have a USB-C port.